# Determine date order obtained using nl_langinfo(D_FMT) on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, date, date-format

I am trying to determine the order of date string on Linux. The user might set the locale in "%d/%m/%Y", "%m/%d/%Y" or "%Y/%m/%d" order. For the separator character, the user can enter a slash (/), a dash (-), a period (.), a comma (,), or B (or b), which indicates a blank space.

char *date = nl_langinfo(D_FMT);
This string date contains "%d/%m/%Y".

Is there any API that will determine the order of date by using this string?

Comment: Look for the sub-strings `"%d"`, `"%m"` and `"%Y"` (or `"%y"`). Then compare the three pointers to see which is first, second and third.

Comment: What is an "order" of a "string"? `For the separator character, the user can enter` User can do anything and enter anything. Is this a reference from somewhere, or is this some sort of specification?

Comment: The user might want to display the date in the order DMY, MDY, YMD.

The [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=categories-lc-time-category)
 describes the d_fmt category.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about strings is that they are really a simple array of (null-terminated) characters, and that each element of the array (each character) follow directly after one another. From that we can say that a pointer to one element will have a strict ordering compared to a pointer to another element.

So if we can get pointers to each of the three sub-strings (`"%d"`, `"%m"` and `"%Y"` (or `"%y"`, don't forget about this)) then we can detect their relative order in the string.

And to get a pointer to a sub-string there are two ways, depending on language. In C++ you can put the string into a `std::string` and its [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function to get the sub-strings position (instead of a raw pointer) and compare to each other:

```
std::string date_format = nl_langinfo(D_FMT);
auto day_pos   = date_format.find("%d");
auto month_pos = date_format.find("%m");
auto year_pos  = date_format.find("%Y");

if (year_pos == std::string::npos)
{
    // No "%Y", try "%y"
    year_pos  = date_format.find("%y");
}

if (day_pos != std::string::npos && month_pos != std::string::npos && year_pos != std::string::npos)
{
    // Have all three

    if (day_pos < month_pos && month_pos < year_pos)
    {
        // day-month-year
    }
    else if (year_pos < month_pos && month_pos < day_pos)
    {
        // year-month-day
    }
    // Etc...
}
else
{
    // Another format, possibly only day and month?
    // Handle as above
}
```